# Mongoose - Increment very large number

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to save a very large 16 digit number in my db like below:

`{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5eb550aae41d233f1058efb0"),
    "id" : 1,
    "referenceId" : 100000000000000000,
    "__v" : 0
}`
  and increment its value by 1. But for some reason, the number I have saved in db doesnt increment.
This is what I have done:

```
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Incrementing the only document in 'referenceIds' collection by 1
    ReferenceId.findOneAndUpdate(
        { id: 1 },
        { $inc: { referenceId: 1 } }
    ).then(res => {
        // If no document found, creating new one.(This is a one time activity)
        if (!res) {
            let referenceIdDoc = new ReferenceId({
                id: 1,
                referenceId: 100000000000000000
            })
            referenceIdDoc.save()
                .then(res => {
                    resolve(res.referenceId);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    reject(err);
                });
        } else {
            resolve(res.referenceId);
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        reject(err);
    });
});
```

But the reference that is saved in db is as follows:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5eb554cb80a31d3670afddcb"),
"id" : 1,
"referenceId" : 1e+17,
"__v" : 0
}
```

And after the incrementing the 'referenceId' in the above code snippet I have given, 'referenceId' remains the same. i.e 100000000000000000.

**How can I save and increment very big integers like 100000000000000000 in mongodb using NodeJs and Mongoose?**

Can anyone please help me out here? I have been stuck on this issue for hours. Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I have used **mongoose-long** npm module to deal with very large integers and made the following changes in my application:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require('mongoose-long')(mongoose);

let SchemaTypes = mongoose.Schema.Types;

const ReferenceId = mongoose.Schema({
  id: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
referenceId: {
    type: SchemaTypes.Long,
    required: true
}
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("ReferenceId", ReferenceId);
```

. The value is getting incremented as well as expected. Like below:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5eb55c2d83d44f1f2864ff86"),
"id" : 1,
"referenceId" : NumberLong(100000000000000005),
"__v" : 0
}
```

**However, in my NodeJs application, I'm not getting the actual value of 'referenceId'. I get the following Object:**

```
{_bsontype: "Long", low_: 1569325061, high_: 23283064}
```

**Can anyone please tell me how I can get the actual value from db?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `[mongoose-long][1]` npm package while working with mongoose.
You can get the value into your variable. Add 1 and then update the mongoose object.
Let me know if it works for you.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;
require("mongoose-long")(mongoose);
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/appsyoda", { useNewUrlParser: true });

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
db.once("open", function() {
    // we're connected!
    console.log("connected");
});

var SchemaTypes = mongoose.Schema.Types;
var partSchema = new Schema({ someLong: SchemaTypes.Long });

var Part = db.model("Part", partSchema);

var part = new Part({ someLong: "100000000000000005" });

var Long = mongoose.Types.Long;
part.someLong = part.someLong.add(Long.fromString("1"));
console.log(part.someLong.toString());
part.save();
console.log("part " + part.someLong);
```

Crux of the code is .toString() function of Long.
Check http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/long.html this link for details.

Comment: yes, I have used mongoose-long module, and the number is getting saved and getting incremented as expected. Now the only problem is that, I'm not getting the actual value of referenceId in my application. I'm getting something like "Long {_bsontype: "Long", low_: 1569325061, high_: 23283064}". Can you please tell me how I can get the actual value?

Comment: hold on for a few minutes. I will give you a complete solution.

Comment: Thanks Mohit. I have updated my question for your reference.

Comment: @TonyMathew: I have updated my answer, I really hope this helps you.!